# How to multiply pd dataframe by np array?

Tags: python

I'm new here. Please help me.

```
df1:
     A     B     C     D
0    1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
1    5.0   10.0  15.0  20.0
2    10.0  20.0  30.0  40.0

factor:
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
```

I want to multiply the dataframe df1 by the factor.

The output I expect:

```
   A    B    C    D
0  0.1  0.4  0.9  1.6
1  0.5  2.0  4.5  8.0
2  1.0  4.0  9.0  16.0
```

I tried:

```
df1.multiply(factor, axis=1)
```

Then, the error message shows, "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,) (4,)."

Answer (score 1):

Trust in Python's concept of simplicity:

```
a = np.asarray([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])

df1 *= a
#output
     A    B    C     D
0  0.1  0.4  0.9   1.6
1  0.5  2.0  4.5   8.0
2  1.0  4.0  9.0  16.0
```

This re-calculates the values in your data frame as desired because it utilises [`numpy` broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).
As @Alex mentioned in the comments, you don't need a `numpy` array as factor `a`, a Python list will work equally well. And the concept can of course be extended, you don't need to apply it to the whole data frame:

```
b = [0.3, 0.7]
df1[["A", "D"]] += b
```

Comment: You don't need to convert to an array (explicitly).

Comment: I just did it, because the OP said, it was a numpy array.  Will add this comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! I posted a similar question. Can you take a look at it as well? Thank you.